# How do I access a structures component in the Sorted list. sortedList.GetByIndes(i).name?

Tags: c#, structure, sortedlist

Basically how do I access the component of a structure in my Sorted List (keys are strings and values are the structure). The structure is Section and one of the components of it is called name. How do I access that component. `linkedList.GetByIndex(i).name` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Does [this related question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234181/getting-i-th-value-from-a-sortedlist-or-sorteddictionary) help?

Comment: @DannySchneider the code is simply i have a structure called Section (string name;SortedList list;) and then i have a class (string indentifier; SortedList sections;) so the sections list contained in the class has the value of Section structure. I need to output the name of the structure. I managed to make a separate variable for the structure and convert it from type object into it but it seems not optimized so is there any other way?

Comment: @AxelKemper not at all, I don't know how you linked structures to ith value of a list. Congratz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate my comment:

```
struct A
{
    public string name;
}
static void Demo()
{
    //  using System.Collections.Generic;
    SortedList<string, A> list = new SortedList<string, A>();

    list.Add("k0", new A { name = "name0" });

    var name0 = list.Values[0].name;
}
```

To access the first struct in the example list, use `list.Values[0]` or `list["k0"]`. You can then access the `.name` property of the struct.

Comment: So I legit deleted all the code and started again from scratch I just made some classes and I'm getting null pointer exceptions aka some of my lists which is an element of my class isn't assign to but I declared it and used the empty constructor like: List<Section> shoppingList=new List<Section>();. Is there any way I can send a large amount of code to you? :D

Comment: I can't do so because I don't have 15 reputation. But did you mean click the check mark thing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, the Post from @AxelKemper should help.

A simple example:

```
public struct Section
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SortedList<string, string> List { get; set; }
}

public class SectionsClass
{
    public string Indentifier { get; set; }
    public SortedList<string, Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass()
    {
        var sc = new SectionsClass
        {
            Indentifier = "A",
            Sections = new SortedList<string, Section> {
                {"1", new Section { Name = "AA" } },
                {"2", new Section { Name = "AB" } },
            }
        };

        Debug.WriteLine(sc.Sections.ElementAt(0).Value.Name); // AA
    }
}
```

UPDATE: insert "using System.Linq;" as "ElementAt" is an extension method from Linq

Comment: Is this the same with Sorted lists?

Comment: Yeah sorted list doesn't contain  ElementAt